# How to extract result from a generator object that created by executor.map()

Tags: python, numpy, generator, concurrent.futures

I'm  trying to test `concurrent.futures` to speed calculation. Here is the test code:

```py
import concurrent.futures
import numpy as np
import random


def task(n):
    c = np.sum(n)
    # print sum result
    print(c)
    return c


# generate a 3D array
b = np.random.rand(2, 3, 100)

executor = concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor(max_workers=5)

# along axis=2 to do sum in task function
v = executor.map(np.apply_along_axis(task, 2, b))

list(v)
```

I can see `executor.map()` does calculation, as `print(c)` in `task` function can print `sum` result.

The questions are:

1. How to get the data from `v`, which is a generator object?
2. When I use `list(v)`, it gives `[]` as a result. Why?

Comment: Using `concurrent.futures` with a thread pool will not help with CPU-bound tasks.  Python threading only works if the tasks are I/O bound, and spend most of their time waiting.  Otherwise, the GIL (global interpreter lock) means that only one Python thread can be running at any given time.

Comment: That `apply_along..` call returns an array.  It calls `task` several times and collects the results in an array.  All this before the `map` acts.

Comment: `np.sum(b, axis=2)` is the fastest way.

Comment: Thank hpaulj, I know np.sum(b, axis=2) is the way to calculate the array sum. The main purpose of the code is to go thought this path for other problems in my hand. As Tim Roberts says, I think I should use "ProcessPoolExecutor" instead of "threadPollExecutor"  to my real problems.  Now the real question  is how to extract data from the generator object "v"? I have read many papers and videos about generator fuc, but none of them talk about how to iterate data (result) out from this one.

Answer (score 1):

The main issue is a misunderstanding.  `np.apply_along_axis` is going to call the function `task` repeatedly (but serially), and then return the modified array.  You then pass that returned array to `executor.map`, when it's actually expecting to find a function.

So, it's not `executor.map` that is calling your function, it is `apply_along_axis`.

As I mentioned above, if your task is CPU-bound, Python threading is not going to help with the time.  Perhaps you should ask a different question that includes more details of your situation, instead of inventing a fake one like this.

Answer (score 0):

First understand what `apply` does, or does not

Modify the function to be a bit more diagnostic:

```
def task(n):
    print(n)
    c = np.sum(n)
    # print sum result
    print(c)
    return c
```

And with smaller array:

```
In [205]: b = np.arange(24).reshape(2, 3, 4)
In [207]: np.apply_along_axis(task, 2, b)
[0 1 2 3]
6
[4 5 6 7]
22
[ 8  9 10 11]
38
[12 13 14 15]
54
[16 17 18 19]
70
[20 21 22 23]
86
Out[207]: 
array([[ 6, 22, 38],
       [54, 70, 86]])
```

`apply` passes successive "rows" of `b` to `task`.  The result is a (2,3) array - the `b` array reduced along its last axis.

If `task` really is just this simple, you can get the same result much faster with an axis parameter.

```
In [208]: np.sum(b, axis=2)
Out[208]: 
array([[ 6, 22, 38],
       [54, 70, 86]])
```

Before spending a lot effort into getting threaded/multiprocessing working, try to take full use of `numpy` compiled code.

`apply` is essentially:

```
In [209]: np.array([[task(row) for row in plane] for plane in b])
[0 1 2 3]
6
[4 5 6 7]
22
...
Out[209]: 
array([[ 6, 22, 38],
       [54, 70, 86]])
```

Modifying `task` to omit the prints, we can compare the times:

```
In [211]: timeit np.apply_along_axis(task1, 2, b)
154 µs ± 6.86 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
In [212]: timeit np.array([[task1(row) for row in plane] for plane in b])
72 µs ± 53.6 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10,000 loops each)
In [213]: timeit np.sum(b, axis=2)
10.9 µs ± 18.5 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)
```

===

From the `executor.map` docs

```
map(func, *iterables, timeout=None, chunksize=1)
```

the first arg is `func`, a function, not the result of calling a function.  The second one or more iterables.

It may be possible to use

```
map(task, b.reshape(-1,100))
```

and get back a list of "row" sums.

```
In [217]: v = executor.map(task, b.reshape(-1, 4))
[0 1 2 3]
6
[4 5 6 7]
22
[ 8  9 10 11]
38
...
In [218]: v
Out[218]: <generator object Executor.map.<locals>.result_iterator at 0x7f235c85be40>
In [219]: list(v)
Out[219]: [6, 22, 38, 54, 70, 86]
```

For this small example, and my modest machine, the multiprocessing doesn't help at all:

```
In [220]: timeit list(executor.map(task1, b.reshape(-1, 4)))
308 µs ± 35.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
```

Comment: hpaulj: many thanks. Again example in original code is just for understanding how to use concurrent.futures.  Can you help me if change ThreadPoolExecutor to ProcessPoolExecutor? I got " A process in the process pool was terminated abruptly while the future was running or pending." when I am following your example. 'import concurrent.futures
import numpy as np
import random

def task(n):
    c = np.fft.fft(n)
    return c
b = np.arange(24).reshape(2, 3, 4)
 with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor(max_workers=5) as executor:
    v = executor.map(task, b.reshape(-1, 4))
list(v)'